# Aligning Buttons with rails code, css, and html

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

I have two buttons in my form, I am using a CSS sheet to layout the tables and I want to have the buttons in the last row, but I want them side by side.

My current code looks like

```
<button><%= link_to "Edit", edit_user_path(u.id), { :method =>get } %></button>
<button><%= link_to "Delete", user_path(u.id), { :method => delete, :class=>destroy, data: {confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></button>
```

[image]

If I change it to:

```
<button><%= button_to "Edit", edit_user_path(u.id), { :method =>get } %></button>
<button><%= button_to "Delete", user_path(u.id), { :method => delete, :class=>destroy, data: {confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></button>
```

[image]

The buttons end up side by side, but with an extra button from the button tag. 
If I change it to:

```
<td><%= button_to "Edit", edit_user_path(u.id), { :method =>get } %>
<%= button_to "Delete", user_path(u.id), { :method => delete, :class=>destroy, data: {confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
```

[image]

The buttons are in the same row, but are horizontally alligned.

Is there a way to get this to correctly display in the center of the column with both buttons? Perhaps add something in the CSS that tells it what to do with the button call instead?

Comment: I don't get the issue... They are side by side in your first image aren't they..?

Comment: They are side by side, I am looking to see if perhaps there is a better way to do it, and or to align them center.

Comment: The problem is `button_to` doesn't create a `<button>` it creates a `<form class="button_to" method="post" action="#"><input type="submit" value="Edit" /><input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="x" /></form>`  Try targeting the `button_to` class instead of `<button>` in your css

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap the buttons in a div like so: https://jsfiddle.net/5th07vq6/

**HTML:**

```
 <div class="center">
     <button>Edit</button>
     <button>Delete</button>
 </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.center {
     width: 50%;
     margin: 0 auto;
}
```